# Exposed Docker ports not accessible from host jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, port

I'm running a docker container which services

I want to be accessible from my host.

In the container there is a jenkins instance running which is accessible from the outside.

For testing purposes I want to deploy a php dev webserver(on port 8000) in the same container and make it accessible in the same way the jenkins interface is accessible.

In order to achieve this, I exposed/mapped the respective ports. Unfortunately this is not working. docker inspect shows the following output:

```
[
{
    "Id": "dcd48abd7c5a39c5525a4d3e4a6fbb71de4cc75a73c21fb96be9ee4c4a2ce523",
    "Created": "2021-09-10T13:15:35.002583738Z",
    "Path": "/sbin/tini",
    "Args": [
        "--",
        "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 91930,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2021-09-10T14:22:19.643217522Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2021-09-10T14:21:58.435758038Z"
    },
    "Image": "sha256:482543872bd95ba0a45d1dcb58a111e6ec400d3d1fe623c49e29b8fe96a8115d",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/dcd48abd7c5a39c5525a4d3e4a6fbb71de4cc75a73c21fb96be9ee4c4a2ce523/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/dcd48abd7c5a39c5525a4d3e4a6fbb71de4cc75a73c21fb96be9ee4c4a2ce523/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/dcd48abd7c5a39c5525a4d3e4a6fbb71de4cc75a73c21fb96be9ee4c4a2ce523/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/dcd48abd7c5a39c5525a4d3e4a6fbb71de4cc75a73c21fb96be9ee4c4a2ce523/dcd48abd7c5a39c5525a4d3e4a6fbb71de4cc75a73c21fb96be9ee4c4a2ce523-json.log",
    "Name": "/jenkins-master",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
    "ExecIDs": [
        "2399ce39070f1fd2797c1a6546c88e6f67c910ccb76f51ba9fe82a55872d8bb0"
    ],
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "8000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8000"
                }
            ],
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupnsMode": "host",
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            0,
            0
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dd86fde4c925a6719f88eaab536c7b69cda3110ae248ab96b5e0893b7baffe93-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/daff89f11d794674b05ea4b21dac36bde8b49255e442bf98e9f065e50d7663a2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1fde4720d5265a9423568ac118f68f3e017fd65ddd08a1c656d62baec21c9b38/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/3ca42e9a13186a031f9f5fa411fe0f3fa206c227e7131fb238df46fb5198b064/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/792cc2135989fbad42bd2748b7ae22d341c2a71056c1ca514cbda0c60795b06d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d4ec55422929984d046d388f375f661f3780e437cb55684a7948bfe8abb7ae55/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/44270788b46b4fb55672b2d4e885783e4add809091ca6bf6e5b667fbb6fbb337/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/617d337c627950f8b56144ecc75311e5b1e28ec15aeba88026a862ea3d28a5fc/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fbdb555e550c5373608405b5b9fe6f1ab0f13898d68978f8be0c30d76f549380/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/419bfbf8f74ad45cd1623a3246a08a3172e1788689aa36562e0edd16e49b856b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/540039b7235ddc6f74a1ba6b24edfeddfbd4aa908a3ecb0e0d9df55b9297c004/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/6e0a9ba59de2c9a13bab49107dc51e438b9514148bfdafa652a53fb65375cc87/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2c67a559c023f2429c4bd1344eb8a7a5fc51860faa6b5c1671980b1867747cb5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bcb20d3aaba31b0fe0480e83c7af6e2c0b7314a2d4d1655da0e6b7f46570f1de/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/12d0962adcd9ee65dc97765aa2306b963af2ae5f3f7603d436556d420c4c7b52/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/cd20241417624ea93282b2580e5e3b944b634f3b6fbc35760a7101f7d263645b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1ebf8c9ba9cb7499abc516477c90f7a1d4c251cf44aa50aa2c6a19b2e2e8433b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/1d91cb07c3ebbf1379baa54fc5714b827a8d943dea3070b9235106476529116d/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dd86fde4c925a6719f88eaab536c7b69cda3110ae248ab96b5e0893b7baffe93/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dd86fde4c925a6719f88eaab536c7b69cda3110ae248ab96b5e0893b7baffe93/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dd86fde4c925a6719f88eaab536c7b69cda3110ae248ab96b5e0893b7baffe93/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [
        {
            "Type": "volume",
            "Name": "87049f1725983459b5261c6aa0efc7f57ddbe8610393a00f579f5421165cd7d3",
            "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/87049f1725983459b5261c6aa0efc7f57ddbe8610393a00f579f5421165cd7d3/_data",
            "Destination": "/var/jenkins_home",
            "Driver": "local",
            "Mode": "",
            "RW": true,
            "Propagation": ""
        }
    ],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "dcd48abd7c5a",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "jenkins",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": true,
        "AttachStderr": true,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "50000/tcp": {},
            "8000/tcp": {},
            "8080/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "PATH=/opt/java/openjdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "LANG=C.UTF-8",
            "JENKINS_HOME=/var/jenkins_home",
            "JENKINS_SLAVE_AGENT_PORT=50000",
            "REF=/usr/share/jenkins/ref",
            "JENKINS_VERSION=2.311",
            "JENKINS_UC=https://updates.jenkins.io",
            "JENKINS_UC_EXPERIMENTAL=https://updates.jenkins.io/experimental",
            "JENKINS_INCREMENTALS_REPO_MIRROR=https://repo.jenkins-ci.org/incrementals",
            "COPY_REFERENCE_FILE_LOG=/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log",
            "JENKINS_ENABLE_FUTURE_JAVA=true",
            "JAVA_HOME=/opt/java/openjdk"
        ],
        "Cmd": null,
        "Image": "jenkins/jenkins",
        "Volumes": {
            "/var/jenkins_home": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "/sbin/tini",
            "--",
            "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {
            "org.opencontainers.image.description": "The Jenkins Continuous Integration and Delivery server",
            "org.opencontainers.image.licenses": "MIT",
            "org.opencontainers.image.source": "https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins",
            "org.opencontainers.image.title": "Official Jenkins Docker image",
            "org.opencontainers.image.url": "https://www.jenkins.io/",
            "org.opencontainers.image.vendor": "Jenkins project",
            "org.opencontainers.image.version": "2.311"
        }
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "d4ed8fd702f544e1df32f41ab6d562e530dcdabcd39903df926238505dd2926a",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "50000/tcp": null,
            "8000/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8000"
                },
                {
                    "HostIp": "::",
                    "HostPort": "8000"
                }
            ],
            "8080/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                },
                {
                    "HostIp": "::",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/d4ed8fd702f5",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "f3f27ad47be4e64a091a3c20c59e26d8d6f85e58937c2acf850e5788504258fa",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "2095a9a68e2f4078e9c28fda68afe72238108c2b56f09a905aceae8bc207a534",
                "EndpointID": "f3f27ad47be4e64a091a3c20c59e26d8d6f85e58937c2acf850e5788504258fa",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]

docker ps gives the folling output:

```
dcd48abd7c5a   jenkins/jenkins           "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   3 days ago    Up 3 days             0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp               jenkins-master
```

Anyhelp to make this work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] (and possibly delete the long diagnostic output)?  How do you start the PHP application (container)?  How do you start the Jenkins container?  What URL are you trying to connect to, from where, and what response do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was found and solved. Its was due to the misconfiguration of the service that i wanted to be exposed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).